# No wifi or Bluetooth on HP 17z laptop

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, hp

I'm new to Linux and just got an HP 17z laptop I put elementary on. It seems to be a common problem that once it's installed, the wifi goes out. I can't seem to find a fix that works, especially since I don't have a way to connect the laptop to the internet (no home internet or Ethernet cable). I do have access to my work computers with internet tho so I can put any drivers on a USB and get it on my computer that way, but I'm struggling to find out which drivers I need and what to do with them once I get them.

From what I can tell, this seems to be relevant info:
RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe wireless network adapter: [10ec:c821]
Subsystem: HP RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless network adapter: [103c:831a]

Please let me know what other info I need to give. (Also, first post, so please tell me if I did anything wrong)

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to update your kernel version to have a driver that works.

[Here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.2/) you have the version 5.2 which is a mainline kernel but should work on your laptop.
You need to download the files marked with a black line.

[image: Kernel files]

Then save it to any folder on your HP 17z laptop.
Press right click> open in terminal and write the following on the window that appears: `sudo apt install ./lin*.deb`. This should install everything, now you need to reboot and it should be done!