# Keyboard and TouchPad stops working in Elementary OS

Tags: release-juno, keyboard, touchpad, elementary-website

I recently switched from Windows to Elementary OS and i have noticed several times that the keyboard as well as the touch pad stops working. If i restart my laptop, then everything seems to work fine for sometime but then again the same problem occurs. This never happened in Windows. Please help.

Comment: What computer do you have? We need more info about the hardware (touchpad and keyboard model) to help you.

Comment: @Maccer i have a HP-Convertible-x360-11-ab000nx

Comment: You could try to upgrade your kernel version and maybe that solves the issue. [Here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/19407/no-wifi-or-bluetooth-on-hp-17z-laptop/19482#19482) you have a guide with all the details you need to upgrade the kernel.

Comment: This also happens to me, specially when come back from hibernation, some keys does not appear when I type, looks like the keyboard is broken, but than, in some minutes it gets back to work normally. Sometimes when this happens, if i keep pressing the key for a long time it shows the character. I have a thinkpad x240, OS 5 Juno

Answer (score 2):

In my case elementary OS was working fine until I install so many things including software update from app center, then I leave my laptop and when I came back the keyboard and mouse does not work.

I was logged in automatically and I can see the desktop with the mouse pointer, but I'm unable to move the mouse nor type anything on my keyboard (not even changing the screen brightness or volume on function keys)

The solution in my case since I cannot type anything:

1. I boot into elementary OS secure boot (the the one that has Advanced Options)
2. Select Network to enable network
3. Select Root to enable typing through command line
4. Type `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all`

I got the answer from [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174091/mouse-and-keyboard-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04/174095), maybe it can help you with other information

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Or maybe it was because i was downloading ubuntu's iso and elementary os got scared

Answer (score 0):

I do have a laptop with dual graphics: discrete gtx 1050 nvidia and integrated intel. After update I've got 460 over 450 nvidia driver version the strange thing happened: while I'm using nvidia card everything works just fine, however after choosing the intel one by issuing `sudo prime-select intel` and restarting the system I'm able to type my password to log in, however as soon as I get logged in mouse/touchpad and keyboard stop working completely. The only solution to hard reset and upon login session press `CTRL + ALT + F1` to get into tty and from there type `sudo prime-select nvidia` then type `reboot`. It's not a perfect solution though! It limits the possibility to use integrated intel graphics which is much less consumable on battery. How to solve the problem properly? ps. elementary os hera 5.1